# pageslts error : Label `pagesLTS.<scheme>.local' shall be overriddenalthough it does not yet exist

Tags: errors, pageslts

With the pageslts package, I get the 3 following errors:

```
! Package undolabl Error: Label `pagesLTS.roman.local' shall be overridden although it does not yet exist.
See the undolabl package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.... \undonewlabel{pagesLTS.roman.local}

! Package undolabl Error: Label `pagesLTS.roman' shall be overridden although it does not yet exist.

! Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>\c@pagesLTS.roman.1.local.count \end{document}
```

When I try to set a default numbering scheme at the beginning of the document (like roman), change it again just after the `\begin{document}` for another scheme (like alph, without writting anything), write something (until a new page is created), and try to get back to the original scheme (roman).

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pageslts}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Alph} 
alpha

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
arabic 

\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman} 
roman

\end{document}
```

Those errors don't occur if I don't use the scheme set at the beginning of the document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's the reason for setting a page numbering scheme and then reset it before outputting a page?

Comment: the reason is to have a default numbering scheme in the prehambule, and be able to change it juste before the beginning of the document. For example, a package could set a default numbering scheme, and then the user could change it just after loading the package

Comment: I don't think you can do much about this.

Comment: You could provide a package option to handle it. Can your package not avoid loading `pageslts`? That would be my preference, if only because the load order here is tricky and you don't know what else a user might be loading.

Comment: it is for a personnal package, that will contain all the package I use so the load order won't be an issue here. I use pageslts because I want a different page numbering (with last page) for normal pages and appendices pages, and pageslts seems to do the trick